# How fill empty value in Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

How to show Pie with empty values in data and fill some color?
Example: just set some value more then 0
https://codesandbox.io/s/pie-chart-of-two-levels-forked-2uigq2?file=/src/App.tsx

I try set fillOpacity and fillRule

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.